# How to check an input words against several arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I need to test all the words entered into an input against 3 objects and determine which array they belong to so I can output a URL to an API.
I want to achieve this with Javascript/jQuery.

For example if the input had these words: `keyword1` `keyword2` `keyword3`  `keyword5`

All keyword entries will be added from a autocomplete plugin.

I then need to test them against 3 arrays.

```
var array1 = ["keyword2", "keyword6"];
var array2 = ["keyword3", "keyword4"];
var array3 = ["keyword1", "keyword5"];
```

I need to determine what array they came from so I can output a URL and add the values to specific keys in a URL.

Example:

domain.com/api?array1= [insert keyword(s)] &array2= [insert keyword(s)] &array3= [insert keyword(s)]

The keywords need to be sent as an array and must have spaces replaced with dashes.

I am using jQuery to perform a GET request with the URL generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the code shorter by creating an array of arrays but this works

```js
var input = "keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 keyword5".split(" ");
var array1 = ["keyword2", "keyword6"];
var array2 = ["keyword3", "keyword4"];
var array3 = ["keyword1", "keyword5"];
var arr1=[],arr2=[],arr3=[];

$.each(input,function(_,keyword) {
  if ($.inArray(keyword,array1) !=-1) arr1.push(keyword);
  if ($.inArray(keyword,array2) !=-1) arr2.push(keyword);
  if ($.inArray(keyword,array3) !=-1) arr3.push(keyword);
});
var url = "domain.com/api/?",keywords="";
if (arr1.length>0) keywords += "&array1="+arr1.join(",");
if (arr2.length>0) keywords += "&array2="+arr2.join(",");
if (arr3.length>0) keywords += "&array3="+arr3.join(",");
if (keywords.length>0) url += keywords.substring(1).replace(/ /g,"-");
console.log(url)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry. I hadn't tested it yet, I was just remarking on how easy it seemed. I have now implemented it and it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the array objects into a parent array and then loop it

```
var parentArray = [
    ["keyword2", "keyword6"],
    ["keyword3", "keyword4"],
    ["keyword1", "keyword5"]
]

$.each(parentArray,function(key,value){
    //here you can check
    $.each(value,function(key1,value1){
            if('your key word') ==  value1{
              // then the array you are looking for would be "key" of that particular loop
            }
    });


});
```

**EDIT:** Now, this should definitely work

Comment: yeah...my bad,I forgot to add the variable...now check it, i have edited it

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It's a clever solution. Except you meant `var parentArray = [
    array1,
    array2,
    array3
]`

Comment: It is clever now the typos have been corrected :) Remove the last comma from parentArray and you're good

Comment: @JeremyThille: thnx for the suggestion

Comment: You are missing the key in the URL - array1=...&array2=... which is the more complicated part

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS version:

```
var words = 'keyword1 keyword2 keyword3 keyword5';

// first create an object that contains your arrays
var dict = {
    array1: ["keyword2", "keyword6"],
    array2: ["keyword3", "keyword4"],
    array3: ["keyword1", "keyword5"]
}

// start building up a new object that mirrors the existing one
// but that only contains those keywords that are in the input string
function buildURLObj(dict, words) {
    var out = {};

    // split the keywords string into an array
    words = words.split(' ');

    // loop over the object
    for (var p in dict) {
        out[p] = [];

        // loop over the array of keywords
        for (var i = 0, l = words.length; i < l; i++) {

            // if the keyword in the array, push it to the
            // temporary object
            if (dict[p].indexOf(words[i]) > -1) {
                out[p].push(words[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // return the completed URL using createURL
    return createURL(out);
}

// create a URL from the new object
function createURL(arr) {
    var url = [];
    for (var p in arr) {

        // if the array is not empty, don't add it to the completed URL
        // otherwise start building up the URL string
        if [arr[p].length) {
            var subURL = [];
            subURL.push(p);
            subURL.push('[' + arr[p].join('-') + ']');
            url.push(subURL.join('='));
        }
    }

    // return the completed URL
    return url.join('&');
}

// "array1=[keyword2]&array2=[keyword3]&array3=[keyword1-keyword5]"
buildURL(dict, words);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wf6mkzLs/3/)